# How do you setup user quotas for disk storage?

Tags: nfs, quota

The lpic exam shows how to setup user disk quotas in the /etc/fstab.

Source
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LPI_Linux_Certification/Managing_Disk_Quota

Example

```
/dev/fd0  /home/yann/mnt auto    rw,noauto,user,usrquota 0 0
/dev/hda5 /home     ext2    defaults,usrquota,grpquota 1 2


touch /mnt/aquota.user
touch /home/aquota.user
touch /home/aquota.group 
chmod 600  /mnt/aquota.user 
chmod 600  /home/aquota.user 
chmod 600  /home/aquota.group
```

It seems to me that a large organization with hundreds of users would need a more complex setup than editing fstab entries for each user.

Is this really how large organizations (like a university) would setup disk quotas?

Without going into specific product recommendations, are there alternative methods for restricting disk usage?

Comment: To enable quota checking, you only edit fstab once for each filesystem, not once for each user. After that, use `edquota` or `setquota` to set up quotas for individual users.